# wkhtmltopdf and different orientation in one document

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf

Is it possible to make pdf with [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) with different page orientation: for example, one page should be portrait and one landscape. I know what orientation is a GLOBAL option, but I heard about meta tags which I can embed directly in my html, are they useful for my purpose?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but how will you know where a "page" begins and ends? Since HTML doesn't have page-breaks, how could you hope to achieve this in the general case? Maybe in your case there's something specific about the HTML you're converting? If so, maybe you could split the document and create two different PDFs that you later merge.

Comment: I have my own html which markup by millimeters.